# Cannot return view in laravel from a controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to return a view in **Laravel** controller but it is not working but instead when i echo that view then it works. I just want to know why this is happening?

This doesn't work:

```
return view('themes.tables.home');
```

and

```
echo view('themes.tables.home');
```

that does.

Comment: it is showing any error when you are working with return??

Comment: "it is not working" is not an overly helpful problem description! Make sure you have `APP_DEBUG` set to `true` in your .env-file and please tell us the exact error message that you get.

Comment: no it is not showing any errors and my  APP_DEBUG is true.

Comment: If you just get a blank page, either your view-file is empty (maybe you forgot to extend the master layout?) or you get a lower level error, maybe from the webserver. Check the HTTP response code that you get (e. g. with Chrome Develeoper Tools) and make sure to check the server logs (not the application logs). Are other parts of your application working correctly?

Comment: Try to just a basic hello world html in home.blade.php

Comment: Would you be able to show your whole controller method?

Comment: return view('themes::tables.home');

Comment: @PrashantGPatil what's the `::` for?

Comment: i think u used themes as module

Comment: Is that method being called by another controller? If so you cant return the view i think you have to return the function thats calling that function if so

Comment: execute the `php artisan config:cache` to refresh your cache in your .env file and try to return the view again. And please, if you are getting an error, edit your question and put it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
return View::make('themes.tables.home');
```